# God's photo kept in temple

Tags: belief

Is it correct to take the God's photos kept in temple by some others under the tree? We should not take the broken ones, I know. Recently I found a new plastic laminated srirangapatna ranganatha swamy photo and the next day a brand new Raghavendra swamy laminated not even the plastic removed. I asked the archaka and took both the photos. Incidentally it was 345th brindavana aradana for Ragavendra swamy on Saturday [Madhya Aradhana]